# Anyway to kill thread/asynctask that run from closed app in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, thread-sleep, android-thread

Is there anyway to kill thread/asynstask from closed android app

My app has to kill asynctask before run new asynctask

I tried    Thread.getAllStackTraces()   and check AsyncTask name  when app open  but I can not kill it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        killThreadByName("AsyncTask");
        LongOperation task = new LongOperation(this);
        task.execute();

    }

    public void killThreadByName(String threadName) throws InterruptedException {
        for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
            if (t.getName().contains(threadName)) {
                t.interrupt();

            }
        }
    }
    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while(true){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    publishProgress("This is number : " + i);
                    Log.i("TEST","NUMBER : " + i);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, values[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
}
```

This app is for counting 1 to 25  and when I close app, it still running.

But when I reopen the app, the old thread can not be killed.

I mean background service (Asynctask) still running forever even I close the app. The problem is if I open this app again I want the old asynctask be killed, and the new asynctask start from 1. now there are many asynctasks if I start this app more than 1 time.

Thank you

Comment: it your application gets killed then their no reference of asyntask or thread available. It will be garbage collected so you don't have to closed or remove it again.

Comment: Use AlarmManager instead, don't use AsyncTask

Comment: add some flag to your thread, which will be checked to decide if it should continue running, and set it to true when the app is closed.

Comment: `new LongOperation(this)` is `this` is `Activity`? Why do you need to passing `Activity` to `AsyncTask` when you don't have that constructor on `LongOperation`?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad choice if you want to count on the background using AsyncTask inside an Activity, because it will lead to Activity leak. I enforce you to use AlarmManager or Service instead. Just for knowledge i will show you how to kill your AsyncTask inside an Activity when the Activity stopped or on the background.
Firstly, you must make a member variable of your AsyncTask

```
private LongOperation task;
```

Then you start your AsyncTask like this

```
task = new LongOperation();
task.execute();
```

Lastly, you stop your AsyncTask from Activity's onStop

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    task.cancel(true);
}
```

Comment: I mean background service (Asynctask) still running forever even I close the app. The problem is if I open this app again I want the old asynctask be killed, and the new asynctask start from 1.
now there are many asynctasks if I start this app more than 1 time.

Comment: @Thanawat.h No. When you close the App, the `AsyncTask` is closed.

Comment: Yes, `AsyncTask` will be terminated if the application closed, but not if the application run on the background. `Service` is not an `AsyncTask`, you can see it here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score -1):

I think you assumed the old `Thread` is alive because the code is not running.

However, I think you are wrong. The problem is that you miss the `execute()` call.

Try the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LongOperation task = new LongOperation(this);
        task.execute(); // <-- New added code
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    publishProgress("This is number : " + i);
                    Log.i("TEST","NUMBER : " + i);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, values[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh i miss it thank you and yes i mean the old thread from this app.

Comment: yes I already execute but this post I didn't copy all of my code, I miss that line. haha @JonZarate

Comment: It still cannot be killed. now I'm using service instead, and it's work.

Comment: @Thanawat.h Then you should post your answer and accept it for others users that come and read it.